# Apache or PHP generating prepending line feed character

Tags: php, apache2, character, prepend

I am trying to generate an XML file in a PHP web application:

```
<?php
... 
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n" . 
...
```

Bizarrely, when using my servers (PHP Version 5.3.8/Apache 2.2.17 and PHP Version 5.3.10-1/Apache 2.2.22 respectively) **a line feed (hex `0a`) character is inserted in the beginning of the output**, resulting in invalid XML that cannot be used. There's [one more online question about this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175870/apache-or-php-inserting-a-newline-at-start-of-every-html-and-xhr-response), unresolved.

So if I try `echo "bug";` I get 4 bytes, not 3: `0a 62 75 67`

However, when using WAMP server locally (PHP 5.4.3/Apache 2.4.2), I get 3 bytes: `62 75 67`.

- Is this a known bug/feature?
- Is it a configuration issue?
- Which is to blame, Apache or
  PHP?
- Do I have to upgrade my servers? I'd rather not.

Comment: What do you get if you don't output the headers? Like what if your whole file is `<?php echo 'foo';exit;`? Do you still get the extra character then?

Comment: @Jason Swett: Yes, just tested it.

Comment: Gotta ask it, you are certain there is no whitespace before opening `<?php`?

Comment: @ficuscr: No whitespace in the beginning. Verified it in a binary editor.

Comment: Test serving `test.html`?  See if Apache is culprit?  Test with command line PHP to see if purely PHP...?  BOM certainly comes to mind but 0a isn't valid, should be three bytes for a UTF-8 BOM right?

Comment: for this code: `ob_start(); echo "bug"; ob_end_flush(); exit;` `0a` exists?

Comment: @ficuscr: Tried serving one correct and one "`0a`" file. The correct one worked, so it didn't prepend anything. The "`0a`" file didn't improve... Means Apache is probably not the cause.

Comment: @mkjasinski right?  My first thought was embedded newline in a header.  I've seen this with set-cookie headers before.  Might be good a good idea to use something like fiddler to better inspect.  Gruber, keep removing as many variables as you can, more you can narrow it down the better.

Comment: @mkjasinski: Got 7 bytes: `ef bb bf 0a 62 75 67`

Comment: back to UTF-8 encoding and BOM then -> EF BB BF / ï»¿ Copy and paste from notepad ++ and back :) ?

Comment: and this: `<?php ob_start(); echo "bug"; ob_end_flush(); exit; ?>` - copy identical, without new lines.

Comment: @ficuscr: Still got the `0a` in front, but the BOM bytes were gone.

Comment: @mkjasinski: Hmm, a `20` (space?) instead of `0a` now when I tried your one-liner. Gotta look into that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the `0a` problem was caused by a trailing Enter character in a PHP file included by my main PHP file. When I removed it from the include file, the `0a` character in my output disappeared.

What I find peculiar about this is the different handling of whitespace between PHP versions that I experienced, and the fact that I still got the `0a` when testing the community's suggestions.

I have no more time to put research into this, but my advice to people experiencing similar problems is to check whether whitespace in include files may play into the equation. In addition, avoid ending the `<?php` tag as suggested by Dan below.

Comment: If your PHP file isn't a template file, it is a wise idea to never close the `<?php` tag at the end of it. And this mainly for this reason. You will never have to worry of trailing spaces or newlines, debugging that is hell.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's an encoding problem. If you are using [UTF8 with BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), there is an extra character at the beginning of the files.
Check the encoding of your files, and convert it to UTF8 without BOM to avoid this extra character.

Comment: I suspected BOM could be involved, but AFAIK it is unrelated to the `0a` character. Notepad++ reports the file is of type UTF8 without BOM. Tried UTF-8 as well. Same results for both.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this. Took me and team an hour to track down. It's amazing. I love PHP so much.

This is what caused it for us:

```
<php
  $code = "blah";
?php>

<EOF>
```

NOTE THE NEWLINE AT THE END OF THE FILE

PHP, in all its transcendent beauty, will interpret this newline as something you're actually trying to send to someone down the wire. It *is* HTML after all. As a result, a maximum of one newline character will be prepended to your response, even if multiple PHP files in your include path end with a newline.

Take special care that any file you include or require, if they end in a newline, anything you echo or print from your current file will be prepended with a newline.

JUST. AWESOME.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was the newline at the beginning

[image]