# why a blank line at the top of the CSV?

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I'm having a problem with a CSV report I'm building with PHP and forcing the browser to download. The issue is that PHP inserts a Line Feed "\n" (0x0A) at the very beginning of the output, so when I open the file I see a non-wanted :) blank line at the top of the content. Funnily, this doesn't happen in my local environment, only on the dev server.

This is an example I deployed to the dev server to test the PHP script:

```
<?php
$doc = array(
   array(
        "header1",
        "header2",
        "header3"
   ),

   array(
        "value11",
        "value12",
        "value13"
   ),

   array(
        "value21",
        "value22",
        "value23"
   ),

   array(
        "value31",
        "value32",
        "value43"
   )
);

ob_start();

$df = fopen( "php://output", 'w' );
foreach ( $doc as $docLine )
{
    fputcsv( $df, $docLine );
}
fclose( $df );

$output = ob_get_clean();

$now = gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" );
header( "Expires: Tue, 012 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" );
header( "Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header( "Last-Modified: {$now} GMT" );

// force download
header( "Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8" );
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.csv\"");
header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" );

echo $output;
```

The dev server is **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS**
with **Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)**
and **PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli)**

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any empty line before the php opening tag `<?php`?

Comment: Tip: comment out output buffer code to force a warning. It'll hopefully tell you the exact file and line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Matei, Gracias a Álvaro. :)

The issue was actually a trailing `\n` after one of the included files of the PHP web site. Not sure why this was affecting a PHP script with no includes when the php.ini has no rules to add any include folder.

Following comments here [Apache or PHP generating prepending line feed character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578271/apache-or-php-generating-prepending-line-feed-character) I checked that apache had nothing to do with this problem by creating a pure html simple page .html extension ;).

To sum up, I'd recommend not to close the `<?php` tag when PHP code is the very last in your page/script.